# How to place a label after all the widgets? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to attach a link to my image but the label is coming over the text.
How can I create a label so that it comes after the text.

self.text_widget is a Text object and I'm adding an image which is a label object and has self.text_widget as it's parent/master. I want this label to be placed after the text entered in the text widget but it's coming over it and covering those text as a result.
This is my code:

```
global my_image,m2,m3 
my_image = PhotoImage(file="images\the-call4.gif") 
label1=Label(self.text_widget, image=my_image) 
label1.pack() 
label1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: callback("http://www.google.com"))
```

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by "comes after the text"

Comment: All what widgets? What does "after" mean? Please add a [mre] to your question.

Comment: You want to position the image after the text?

Comment: Is self.text_widget a `Text` object? If so i don't see any `window_create`.

Comment: self.text_widget is a Text object and I'm adding an image which is a label object and has self.text_widget as it's parent/master. I want this label to be placed after the text entered in the text widget but it's coming over it and covering those text as a result. I'm sorry for not explaining properly.

Comment: Ok `Text` positioning is row.column format with 1.0 as the top left corner. You need to move image to a more appropriate position or insert your text at some other position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the general idea. Insert your text first then apply the image.

Make sure you insert a few line feeds at the end of text.

```py
imageName = "images\the-call4.gif"
#  Suppose this is you text widget
text = tk.Text( master, width = 80, height = 24 )
text.pack( fill = 'both' )

text.insert( '1.0', 'Your text goes here\n\n' )

my_image = tk.PhotoImage( file = imageName ) 
label1 = tk.Label( text, image = my_image )
text.window_create( 'end', window = label1 )
```

Comment: You can use `text.image_create('end', image=my_image)` instead of creating a label and using `.window_create()`.

Comment: Yep sure can, if @Safiya wants to insert image directly instead of inside a label.

Comment: Good one @Safiya, happy coding